# How to automate the Facebook Ad Account process via the API for more than 5 accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-manager

According to the Meta for Developers [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/ad-accounts) if you want to create a Facebook Ad Account via Meta's API, you are only allowed to create 5 accounts through this method.

**excerpt from the documentation:**
*"Ad account creation using the API is limited to 5 ad accounts. To create more than 5 ad accounts, you must do so manually."*

Is there any known workaround for this? It seems a bit limiting to only allow for 5 automated ad account creations for a company. Or am I interpreting this incorrectly? Is it meaning that you can't create more than 5 accounts in the one API call?